# Compiling Haskell code in Cygwin, and some other bugs in Haskell Platform on Windows

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-platform, winghci

I am trying to compile a simple hello world program in Haskell, with Haskell Platform 2011.2.0.1. If I load the code in WinGHCi, and use the GUI to compile, the .exe is created. Then I can run the .exe from Cygwin.

But if I try to compile the code in Cygwin (using `ghc --make`), linker fails. But again, if I compile from the Windows `cmd` prompt, then the compile+linker works fine.

Are there any other environment variables I need to import into Cygwin, to make the compile+linker work in it? I have put the following dirs in my Cygwin PATH: `2011.2.0.1/lib/extralibs/bin`, `2011.2.0.1/bin` (these are the only two valid Haskell related entries that I could see in the Windows environment variables).

I also noticed a couple of invalid items in the Windows environment variables (this looks like a bug in the Haskell installation):

1. (system var) `C/ProgramFiles/Haskell/bin` - this dir does not exist because I have installed Haskell in D disk.
2. (user var) `userxxx/ApplicationData/cabal/bin` - this dir does not exist.

I tried to file a bug report in HaskellPlatform, but I dont have permission to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Without access to your development environment or a listing of the errors that you're getting, I can only assume that the issue is related to the way that you've set up your `PATH`.

GHC on Windows comes bundled with its own `gcc` compiler (for C code) and `ld` linker. If you've installed Cygwin, you've probably also installed the MinGW toolchain, which comes with its own version of `gcc` and `ld`. Then, you've probably made your `PATH` variable list `/usr/bin` before the path to the Haskell Platform binary directories, which makes `ghc` find the MinGW linker and C compiler before it finds the versions that were bundled with GHC.

You need to make sure that the HP directories are listed before the Cygwin directories. It should not be like this:

```
$ echo $PATH
/bin:/usr/bin:.../2011.2.0.1/bin
```

Instead, it should be like this:

```
$ echo $PATH
.../2011.2.0.1/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

This is only a guess at what the issue might be, and you should provide more details for a better diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks. I had suspected that to be the problem, so I had indeed put the haskell items at the front of the PATH. But the problem persists. Here is my PATH: /cygdrive/d/sw2/Haskell Platform/2011.2.0.1/lib/extralibs/bin:/cygdrive/d/sw2/Haskell Platform/2011.2.0.1/bin:.:/cygdrive/d/sw2/jdk6.24/bin:/home/user1/install/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/openwin/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/proc/bin:/usr/etc:/usr/sbin:/cygdrive/d/mswin/jdk6u10/bin:/cygdrive/d/src/mswin_utils/ant_1.7.1/bin:/cygdrive/d/sw2/iverilog/bin

Comment: I made some progress: I reset one env variable at a time, and tried compiling. It turned out that when I delete the items for quicktime (QTJava.zip) and clojure from CLASSPATH, the linker works. But then, why isnt it also failing in windows-cmd, which also has the same CLASSPATH? Is this a bug in the haskell platform?

Comment: Haskell does not use the Java `CLASSPATH` for anything, so it is just a coincidence that it works when you change that variable.

Comment: But this is a consistent coincidence - the same is true for a different user, different machine, and a fresh installation of cygwin and haskell platform. So, if haskell does not use CLASSPATH, then it is a bug in cygwin. Thanks.